# How to register a JDBC Spark dialect in Python?

Tags: python, jdbc, pyspark, dialect, spark-jdbc

I am trying to read from a databricks table. I have used the url from a cluster in the databricks. I am getting this error:

```
 java.sql.SQLDataException: [Simba][JDBC](10140) Error converting value to int.
```

After these statements:

```
jdbcConnUrl= "jdbc:spark://adb....."
testquery="(select * from db.table limit 3)"
testdf=spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url", jdbcConnUrl).option("dbtable", testquery).option("fetchsize", "10000").load()
testdf.show()
```

I have come across all Scala solutions for this issue but I am using python.
I want a python equivalent of this code:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc.{JdbcDialect, JdbcDialects}
JdbcDialects.registerDialect(new JdbcDialect() {
override def canHandle(url: String): Boolean = url.toLowerCase.startsWith("jdbc:spark:")
override
def quoteIdentifier(column: String): String = column
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `%scala` to run the same `scala` code in `databricks` python notebook. 
No need to create separate code for python.

Just add below to the notebook cell and run:

```
%scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc.{JdbcDialect, JdbcDialects}

JdbcDialects.registerDialect(new JdbcDialect() {
    override
    def canHandle(url: String): Boolean = url.toLowerCase.startsWith("jdbc:spark:")
    override
    def quoteIdentifier(column: String): String = column
})
```